# How to set up JSCS/JSHINT rule to invalid code with reserved keywords?

Tags: gulp, jshint, jscs, gulp-jscs

I need to check my JavaScript code for validity using JSCS/JSHINT.
I need to invalidate my code if a "reserved keywords" is present example.

```
require([
], function (
    ) {
    var model = {
        delete: function () {
            alert('hello!')
        }
    };
    model.delete(); // should be INVALID
});
```

This is my task in gulp:

```
gulp.task('validate', function () {
    gulp.src(folders)
        .pipe(jshint())                           // hint (optional)
        .pipe(jscs())                             // enforce style guide
        .on('error', function () { })             // don't stop on error
        .pipe(stylish.combineWithHintResults())   // combine with jshint results
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish')); // use any jshint reporter to log hint and style guide errors
});
```

How to configure JSCS/JSHINT? Thanks.

.jscsrc config:

```
// based on jquery preset
{
    "requireCurlyBraces": [
        "if",
        "else",
        "for",
        "while",
        "do",
        "try",
        "catch"
    ],
    "requireSpaceAfterKeywords": [
        "if",
        "else",
        "for",
        "while",
        "do",
        "switch",
        "return",
        "try",
        "catch"
    ],
    "disallowTrailingComma": true,
    "requireOperatorBeforeLineBreak": true,
    "requireParenthesesAroundIIFE": true,
    "requireMultipleVarDecl": true,
    "requireCommaBeforeLineBreak": true,
    "requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers": "ignoreProperties",
    "requireDotNotation": true,
    "maximumLineLength": 120,
    "validateQuoteMarks": true,
    "disallowMixedSpacesAndTabs": true,
    "disallowTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "disallowMultipleLineStrings": true,
    "requireSpaceBeforeBlockStatements": true,
    "requireSpacesInFunctionExpression": {
        "beforeOpeningCurlyBrace": true
    },
    "requireSpacesInsideObjectBrackets": "allButNested",
    "requireSpacesInConditionalExpression": true,
    "requireSpaceAfterBinaryOperators": true,
    "requireLineFeedAtFileEnd": true,
    "requireSpaceBeforeBinaryOperators": true,
    "requireSpacesInAnonymousFunctionExpression": {
        "beforeOpeningCurlyBrace": true
    },
    "disallowKeywords": [ "with" ],
    "disallowKeywordsOnNewLine": [ "else" ],
    "disallowSpaceAfterObjectKeys": true,
    "disallowSpaceAfterPrefixUnaryOperators": true,
    "disallowSpaceBeforePostfixUnaryOperators": true,
    "disallowMultipleLineBreaks": true
}
```

.jshintrc config:

```
{
    // JSHint Default Configuration File (as on JSHint website)
    // See http://jshint.com/docs/ for more details

    "maxerr": 500, // {int} Maximum error before stopping

    // Enforcing
    "bitwise": true, // true: Prohibit bitwise operators (&, |, ^, etc.)
    "camelcase": false, // true: Identifiers must be in camelCase
    "curly": false, // true: Require {} for every new block or scope
    "eqeqeq": true, // true: Require triple equals (===) for comparison
    "forin": true, // true: Require filtering for..in loops with obj.hasOwnProperty()
    "immed": false, // true: Require immediate invocations to be wrapped in parens e.g. `(function () { } ());`
    "indent": 4, // {int} Number of spaces to use for indentation.
    //       It no longer provides warnings about indentation levels.
    //       You can still use it to set your tab-width but it will be used only for character locations in other warnings.
    "latedef": false, // true: Require variables/functions to be defined before being used
    "newcap": false, // true: Require capitalization of all constructor functions e.g. `new F()`
    "noarg": true, // true: Prohibit use of `arguments.caller` and `arguments.callee`
    "noempty": true, // true: Prohibit use of empty blocks
    "nonew": false, // true: Prohibit use of constructors for side-effects (without assignment)
    "plusplus": false, // true: Prohibit use of `++` & `--`
    "quotmark": false, // Quotation mark consistency:
    //   false    : do nothing (default)
    //   true     : ensure whatever is used is consistent
    //   "single" : require single quotes
    //   "double" : require double quotes
    "undef": true, // true: Require all non-global variables to be declared (prevents global leaks)
    "unused": true, // true: Require all defined variables be used
    "strict": true, // true: Requires all functions run in ES5 Strict Mode
    "maxparams": false, // {int} Max number of formal params allowed per function
    "maxdepth": false, // {int} Max depth of nested blocks (within functions)
    "maxstatements": false, // {int} Max number statements per function
    "maxcomplexity": false, // {int} Max cyclomatic complexity per function
    "maxlen": false, // {int} Max number of characters per line

    // Relaxing
    "asi": false, // true: Tolerate Automatic Semicolon Insertion (no semicolons)
    "boss": false, // true: Tolerate assignments where comparisons would be expected
    "debug": true, // true: Allow debugger statements e.g. browser breakpoints.
    "eqnull": false, // true: Tolerate use of `== null`
    "es5": false, // true: Allow ES5 syntax (ex: getters and setters)
    "esnext": false, // true: Allow ES.next (ES6) syntax (ex: `const`)
    "moz": false, // true: Allow Mozilla specific syntax (extends and overrides esnext features)
    // (ex: `for each`, multiple try/catch, function expression…)
    "evil": false, // true: Tolerate use of `eval` and `new Function()`
    "expr": true, // true: Tolerate `ExpressionStatement` as Programs
    "funcscope": false, // true: Tolerate defining variables inside control statements"
    "globalstrict": false, // true: Allow global "use strict" (also enables 'strict')
    "iterator": false, // true: Tolerate using the `__iterator__` property
    "lastsemic": false, // true: Tolerate omitting a semicolon for the last statement of a 1-line block
    "laxbreak": true, // true: Tolerate possibly unsafe line breakings
    "laxcomma": true, // true: Tolerate comma-first style coding
    "loopfunc": false, // true: Tolerate functions being defined in loops
    "multistr": false, // true: Tolerate multi-line strings
    "proto": false, // true: Tolerate using the `__proto__` property
    "scripturl": false, // true: Tolerate script-targeted URLs
    "shadow": false, // true: Allows re-define variables later in code e.g. `var x=1; x=2;`
    "sub": false, // true: Tolerate using `[]` notation when it can still be expressed in dot notation
    "supernew": false, // true: Tolerate `new function () { ... };` and `new Object;`
    "validthis": false, // true: Tolerate using this in a non-constructor function

    // Environments
    "browser": true, // Web Browser (window, document, etc)
    "couch": false, // CouchDB
    "devel": true, // Development/debugging (alert, confirm, etc)
    "dojo": false, // Dojo Toolkit
    "jquery": true, // jQuery
    "mootools": false, // MooTools
    "node": false, // Node.js
    "nonstandard": false, // Widely adopted globals (escape, unescape, etc)
    "prototypejs": false, // Prototype and Scriptaculous
    "rhino": false, // Rhino
    "worker": false, // Web Workers
    "wsh": false, // Windows Scripting Host
    "yui": false, // Yahoo User Interface

    // Custom Globals
    "globals": {
        "console": false,
        "define": false,
        "require": false
    } // additional predefined global variables
}
```

Comment: I dont quite understand the question. jshint will show this mode.delete()';  as invalid, so can you elaborate a bit more please ?

Comment: @avcajaraville thanks for your comment, I have added my configurations here, unfortunately when running the jscs model.delete() does NOT trow any errors, basically my code is ES5 but I need to have some extra restriction as 'reserved keywords' applied. Please let me know if you have any idea how to solve this problem. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: related: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/744/

Comment: Hi back, I didnt found a solution yet :) If you did, please update the question too. Will check at some point in the future, when I have a bit more time :)